# xdg-mime not doing anything

Tags: mime-types, xdg

Created an empty file in `~` called `test.desktop`. Ran `xdg-mime default test.desktop inode/directory`, which returned success (returned 0). After this, `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` returned `caja-folder-handler.desktop` instead of `test.desktop`. Why did it not change even tho it returned success? I also tried running the commands with superuser privilege, with no success. Also tried `sudo update-desktop-database`, which had seemingly no effect either.

Comment: Try with a desktop file that actually exists in `.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications/`. Note that the argument after `xdg-mime default` is not a filename.

Comment: @Devon this worked, i still think it's weird that it returns 0 when the file doesn't exist in those directories tho.